# How to put a time constraint or pick the first integer solution in PuLP python

Tags: python, pulp

I have a MIP problem which takes extremely long to solve based on the input data set.

How do I print out the first integer solution or limit the problem solve time and if it exceeds that time, I want to print out a feasible solution.

I went through the `PuLP` default solver states. I could not find `feasible` as a state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an option to whatever solver you're using under the hood. Here's an example for the default solver:

`prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(fracGap = 0.00001, maxSeconds = 500, threads = None))`

source [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pulp-or-discuss/GC6Ytid_4lI).

Comment: I tried this. My source was this [link](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/solvers.html). But this does not even start solving. I have `LpSolverDefault.msg = 1`. Is there a way to stop it at the first integer solution instead of a time constraint?